# Code Friendly Block Quotes

Tags: code

I have a self-hosted Wordpress Blog (located at http://www.dougmolineux.com/wp if you're interesed :)

I put a lot of Code Snippets on there, because I'm a programmer. How do I make these "snippets" code friendly? Right now, I am using a simple Blockquote around each one and it converts all single and double apostrophes into strange symbols that will not work when the code is actually copied and pasted.

I am willing to convert to a new theme, or alter an existing one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: geshi]

### Geshi

In general the Geshi library is a popular library for formatting code ( http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

### Geshi as a WordPress plugin

For WordPress several authors "packaged" Geshi in a plugin. take your pick:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=geshi

### The one I use

Personally I use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codecolorer/. This one works by enclosing all pieces of codes with a [cc lang="bla"] code [/cc] tag where you can specify things like language, width, line numbering, etc…

### Example

[image: geshi example]

Comment: I highly recommend codecolorer, though I haven't tried Geshi.

Answer (score 3):

**WP - SyntaxHighlighter Evolved**

This is my favorite one, I had issues with others not processing the content correctly (despite being defined as the right language):

URL:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Description:

> SyntaxHighlighter Evolved allows you
>   to easily post syntax-highlighted code
>   to your site without losing it's
>   formatting or making any manual
>   changes. It uses the SyntaxHighlighter
>   JavaScript package by Alex Gorbatchev.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both options mentioned above are good... but if all you need is to highlight syntax, you will probably need something less robust like the [wp syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) it is compatible with wordpress up to version 3.5.1: as at the time of view you site, i noticed you're still running wordpress 3.3.1, dont worry, this will still work for you.

http://s-plugins.wordpress.org/wp-syntax/assets/banner-772x250.jpg

without line number
[image]

with line number
[image]

Works Fine with PHP, Ruby, Java and many other popular development languages